# Print Swagger url on startup of spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger

An application is hosted on bunch of 'on premise' servers. Every instance's swagger endpoint deployed on different host server is accessed as http://HOSTNAME:SERVER_PORT.swaggerui.html
I have written a method which gets hostname and server port and builds the url. Now I need log the url on application startup. Should I call it after the Main application.run call is over, or is there other way to do this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [ApplicationRunner](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/ApplicationRunner.html)

An example is here: https://www.concretepage.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-commandlinerunner-and-applicationrunner-example